# Android IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

I'm getting crash reports from my app in the marketplace throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException outside of my code with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -2 < 0
1. android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:110)
2. android.text.TextUtils.getCapsMode(TextUtils.java:1573)
3. android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.getCursorCapsMode(BaseInputConnection.java:273)
4. com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:202)
5. com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:57)
6. android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
7. android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
8. android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
9. java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10. java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11. com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12. com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
13. dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It looks like someone has reported this to Google per this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6040

Since there's been no response from Google on this I'm wondering if anyone here has run into this, and more importantly, found a workaround since I can't reproduce it myself and am at a loss as to how to debug it.

I appreciate any insight anyone can offer.

Comment: Can you provide some context/code around how you're using SpannableStringBuilder?

Comment: I can't as I'm not using this class in my code directly. I only have one input textbox in the app and it's defined as a EditTextPreference in an XML file. This seems to work fine on most devices but I do get this error report every so often and I'd like to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by examining the TextView attributes in my xml file. By removing a depreciated attribute (android:capitalize="sentences") the error went away.  However, when I added it back the error did not reappear.  Either way I would recommend anyone having this problem to examine any TextViews for depreciated attributes and remove if possible.